# How to fix Navigation Drawer blocking screen controls in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm currently using a Tabbed Activity and then I added a Navigation Bar. The nav drawer works as intended, you can swipe from the left to open it. But now I cant swipe from side to side to change tabs. I also cant scroll the scrollable fragment. The Nav Drawer is blocking touch input even when it is closed and out of view. Any fixes to this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabBackground="@color/green"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout">

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            >
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add the xml code?

Comment: @PiyushMaheswari I've just added the code. Thanks

Comment: can you share screen shot how your design looks and how you want

Answer (score 0):

First you've to disable the swipe gesture of navigation drawer using below code:
Than only you can use swipe gesture for tabView.

your mainActivity.xml which contains the drawer.

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:openDrawer="start">
         
            <include
                    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
/>
         
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
         
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    
your appBar.xml

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
     
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
     
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
     
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>
     
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I just tried this and I can no longer open the drawer even when using the button. And I still can't do swipe gestures in the tabView. I just updated my post to upload the XML. Thanks!

Comment: please check the above answer and do the correction it should work .